# Pass -std=c++11 as compiler options for CMake

Tags: c++11, cmake

I am trying to compile CMake on linux ec2 AMI with the following commands

```
/bootstrap --prefix=${MYDIR} 
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/mybin/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/mybin/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${MYDIR} 
make
```

and am getting the following error

```
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

After searching for info on `-std=c++11 -std=gnu++11` I still can not find how to set these flags. I find reference to adding flags inside the makefile but I would prefer not to touch that at all.

What line do I add the flag to? is is bootstrap, cmake or make, & how what is the specific syntax. I have tried just adding `-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11` to each with no luck.

gcc 5.3.0 is being used

Comment: If I remember the name correctly, something like `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11` should work.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, that is a great help, I added `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11` to the cmake options and worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

The comment from Joachim is correct that a flag like that would work, but looking at the official instructions... they state all you need is this:

```
./bootstrap --prefix=${MYDIR} && make && make install
```

OR to use cmake. NOT both. If you intend on using cmake, I would highly recommend reading `man cmake` before going further.

As a side note, don't compile unless you absolutely have to. CMake doesn't even provide source tarballs, they expect you to pull directly from their source tree. Either use the package provided by your distribution (preferred) or use an official binary provided by CMake.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to add -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 in command line but prefer using in CMakeLists.txt, try:

```
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
endif()

add_library(<library_name_you_like>, INTERFACE)
target_compile_options(<library_name_you_like> INTERFACE ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS})
```

After above code, now you have a library with c++11 support.

And you can link library_name_you_like to any library/executable like:

```
target_link_libraries(<library_or_executable> <library_name_you_like>)
```